# "Error: Cannot find module 'mysql2/promise'" when running "docker-compose up"

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, npm

I want to use docker compose to connect a node program, in one container, to a MySQL database, in another container. The database seems to start fine, but my index.js file throws an error: `Cannot find module 'mysql2/promise'`

I've tried installing different packages with npm, and even edited various lines in my package.json file in desperation, but to no avail; always the same error. Here are the relevant files, and the output of the commands that work so far.

**$ npm install mysql2**

```
npm WARN simplyanything@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN simplyanything@1.0.0 No license field.

+ mysql2@2.3.3
updated 1 package and audited 101 packages in 3.302s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

**$ sudo npm install mysql2-promise**

```
+ mysql2-promise@0.1.4
updated 1 package and audited 101 packages in 3.772s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "simplyanything",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node index.js"
    },
    "description": "Actions party game",
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
        "mysql2-promise": "^0.1.4",
        "socket.io": "^4.4.1"
    },
    "author": "Chris DeHaan"
}
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
let app = express();
let http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http, {pingTimeout: 60000});

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.get('/', (req, res) => { res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html'); });
http.listen(3000, () => { console.log('listening on *:3000'); });

const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
const pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 100,
    host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
    user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
[.... and so on]
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /sa/
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'
services: 
    web:
      build:
          context: .
      env_file: ./.env
      command: npm start
      volumes: 
          - .:/sa/
          - /sa/node_modules
      ports:
          - $NODE_LOCAL_PORT:$NODE_DOCKER_PORT
      depends_on: 
          - mysqldb
      environment: 
          MYSQL_HOST: mysqldb
    mysqldb:
      image: mysql
      env_file: ./.env
      environment: 
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          MYSQL_DATABASE: $MYSQL_DATABASE
      ports:
          - $MYSQL_LOCAL_PORT:$MYSQL_DOCKER_PORT
      volumes:
          - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
          - mysql_config:/etc/mysql
volumes:
    mysql:
    mysql_config:
```

**.env**

```
MYSQL_USER=simplyanythingUser
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=[Well, you don't need to know this]
MYSQL_DATABASE=simplyanything
MYSQL_LOCAL_PORT=3306
MYSQL_DOCKER_PORT=3306

NODE_LOCAL_PORT=3000
NODE_DOCKER_PORT=3000
```

**$ sudo docker build -t sa .**

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  9.526MB
Step 1/5 : FROM node:latest
 ---> e6bed6a65a54
Step 2/5 : WORKDIR /sa/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3da61e5a5928
Step 3/5 : COPY package.json .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1e7bbeaaa894
Step 4/5 : RUN npm install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 52f36e54d698
Step 5/5 : COPY . .
 ---> e0a50567567b
Successfully built e0a50567567b
Successfully tagged sa:latest
```

**$ node index.js**

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:44273/a1b49bfc-83e7-47dd-ba53-64a8df19ccc9
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
listening on *:3000
```

(and it works in the browser at this point)

**$ sudo docker-compose up**

```
Starting sa_mysqldb_1 ... done
Starting sa_web_1     ... done
Attaching to sa_mysqldb_1, sa_web_1
mysqldb_1  | 2022-02-08 08:31:21+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.28-1debian10 started.
mysqldb_1  | 2022-02-08 08:31:21+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
mysqldb_1  | 2022-02-08 08:31:21+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.28-1debian10 started.
mysqldb_1  | 2022-02-08T08:31:21.660916Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.28) starting as process 1
mysqldb_1  | 2022-02-08T08:31:21.747461Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
web_1      | 
web_1      | > simplyanything@1.0.0 start
web_1      | > node index.js
web_1      | 
mysqldb_1  | 2022-02-08T08:31:23.587278Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
web_1      | node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
web_1      |   throw err;
web_1      |   ^
web_1      | 
web_1      | Error: Cannot find module 'mysql2/promise'
web_1      | Require stack:
web_1      | - /sa/index.js
web_1      |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
web_1      |     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
web_1      |     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
web_1      |     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
web_1      |     at Object.<anonymous> (/sa/index.js:13:15)
web_1      |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
web_1      |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
web_1      |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
web_1      |     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
web_1      |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12) {
web_1      |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
web_1      |   requireStack: [ '/sa/index.js' ]
web_1      | }
web_1      | 
web_1      | Node.js v17.4.0
mysqldb_1  | 2022-02-08T08:31:25.086275Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
mysqldb_1  | 2022-02-08T08:31:25.086445Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
mysqldb_1  | 2022-02-08T08:31:25.277625Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
mysqldb_1  | 2022-02-08T08:31:25.354311Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
mysqldb_1  | 2022-02-08T08:31:25.355558Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.28'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

I'm really stuck because everything it needs seems to be installed, and it works when I run it on the command line with `node index.js` so obviously there's something I'm missing in setting up my container, or getting compose to connect them. Any advice would be much appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: Yes, that seems a reasonable thing to try, but changing the line in question to:
```const mysql = require('mysql2-promise');```
results in an almost identical error:
```Error: Cannot find module 'mysql2-promise'```

Thank you for the comment though.

FYI, my code drew heavily from [this page](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/blob/master/documentation/Promise-Wrapper.md) which might help clarify where I went wrong? I get the feeling the ```mysql2-promise``` package shouldn't be needed at all, and ```mysql2/promise``` is something different, and included in the mysql2 package.

Comment: If you're using docker compose, you should build your image with `docker compose build` or `docker compose up --build`

Comment: @Phil Quite right with the ignore file, I now have ```.dockerignore``` with exactly one line, ```node_modules/``` in it. Thank you.
As for the build command, I assume you mean ```$ sudo docker-compose build```, in which case it runs successfully, the last line being ```Successfully tagged sa_web:latest```. Sadly, ```$ sudo docker-compose up``` then craps out with the same error of a missing module.

Comment: Thanks for the continued support @Phil. I took out ```COPY . .``` from ```Dockerfile```, then ran ```$ npm uninstall mysql2-promise```. My ```package.json``` no longer has mysql2-promises in dependencies. That seems to be an improvement, fewer dependencies. I made a few changes to my Node code to remove promises, so used: ```mysql = require('mysql2');``` Now the error message after ```sudo docker-compose up``` reads: ```Error: Cannot find module 'mysql2'``` so clearly there's a more fundamental problem with my understanding of how to give the container the modules it needs.

Comment: Good question. Yes, I did re-build, the first time running ```$ sudo docker-compose build```, my step 4 went like this:
Step 4/5 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in 4b3ec39e26cc

added 85 packages, and audited 86 packages in 9s

2 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
but now if I do it again, it just says:
Step 4/4 : RUN npm install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 85c9f7f83401

Comment: Here's the output of ```$ sudo docker run -it --rm sa_web bash``` :
root@2f035ffbf9db:/sa# ls -la /sa/node_modules
total 332
[ ... many lines ...]
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root  4096 Feb 10 04:51 mysql2

Comment: The dockerfile seems fine, i think the issue is with the docker-compose file. Do you need the volume for node_modules ?

Comment: Yes, that's a blind mount that keeps the container's folder without overwriting it with your `/sa/` mount. I can't reproduce this at all. [Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/philBrown/f96196de331f73603bd4f981dd0994f9) with everything. Docker version 20.10.11, Docker Compose version v2.2.1

Comment: @Phil, This gist is a wonderful way to show files, I'll do this in the future, thanks. I see the YAML file excludes the database container, which is good to isolate the problem. Still with only this limited file, the same error came up. I tried re-mixing different parts of my originals into your gist, but always an error that basically says ```Error: Cannot find module 'mysql2/promise'``` comes up.

I worry my problem is something more fundamental. Basic advice like _Put all files in the same directory and run commands from there_ (I am) or _You must run as sudo_ (I am) are likely to help.

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant but I never run any of these commands with sudo

Comment: Well, to be sure, I just re-ran ```docker-compose build``` and ```docker-compose up``` without sudo, and got basically the same error message. 

Comment: @cdehaan can you add an answer ? how did you fix it ?

Comment: @MohamedSauood Sadly, I never got this Dockerized correctly, sorry to say.

Comment: @cdehaan thanks for the reply , i switched the package to mysql and removed mysql2 
and followed [this article](https://varsubham.medium.com/nodejs-mysql-docker-compose-ad156cd0c885) to remove the issue

Answer (score 1):

Good afternoon, I had the same problem. You could try to use

```js
npm install mysql2
```

Comment: OP already has `"mysql2": "^2.3.3"` in their `package.json`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).